# Windows stack guard page not triggering in _chkstk

Tags: winapi, memory

I have seen a few crashes "in the wild" where the crash dump shows the code throwing an access violation inside _chkstk when attempting to expand the stack. Windbg shows that _chkstk is touching the guard page, however rather than expanding the stack as it should, it just throws an access violation.

I suspected this might be due to user mode structured exception handlers in the code, however my testing shows that under normal conditions the _chkstk guard page exceptions happen in kernel mode and never even reach the user mode exception handlers.

Hence in this case it looks like the kernel mode guard page exceptions are not being handled for some reason, and instead user mode access violations are triggered.

What could cause this to happen?

Comment: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Comment: True, but note that none of this code is calling IsBadXxxPtr. All _chkstk does is touch each stack frame sequentially to grow the stack.

Comment: The issue with `IsBadXxxPtr` as described in the article is not restricted to that API. The underlying concepts remain unchanged, if you install your own SEH exception filters. I posted the link not so much for the `IsBadXxxPtr` API, but rather for the background information.

Comment: The issue with IsBadXxxPtr is that it can interfere with normal stack operation, e.g. the stack expansion that _chkstk does. In other words yes if you go around manually touching stack pages then bad things can happen, however _chkstk is the one function that is *meant* to touch stack pages, so for it to fail something very out of the ordinary is happening.

Also to re-iterate this has nothing to do with SEH filters. That was my first thought, however as outlined above it is impossible to catch the kernel mode guard exception with an SEH filter.

Comment: There's no chance that this is due to the kernel being unable to expand the stack any further?  Normally, I assume, that would produce a different exception, but that one would presumably be a user-mode exception and you might run into trouble if you caught it and then touched the stack.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely possible. Any ideas why the kernel would be unable to expand the stack? Every time I have seen this the stack has 8k committed, and the single 4k guard page is being touched. It seems too much of a coincidence that the system would just happen to run out of physical memory on multiple occasions at this exact point on a single 4k commit. But other than out of memory I don't know what would prevent the kernel from committing pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an XP/Server 2003 kernel specific issue. On those OS if one thread reads another threads stack then the guard page and TIB state get messed up and any subsequent attempts to grow the stack (_chkstk) result in an access violation. This does not happen on later OS.

In our case we were writing out an in-process minidump containing thread stacks, which would corrupt the stack state as described when the dbghelp library read each threads stack.

**The moral of the story is that it is not safe to generate in-process minidumps, they should always be generated by an external process.**